# Do Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio use the same compiler?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I was wondering if I could trust Visual Studio Code to compile with the same standards as Visual Studio and avoid running Visual Studio on a virtual machine.

Comment: I dont know if it is the same. Visual studio code use Atom editor code.

Comment: Well I presume you want to use it on Linux or OS X. The compilers for Windows and other platforms are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio Code uses Roslyn platform (see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages)). Same as Visual Studio 2015. On Linux and OS X Mono compiler is used.

The IDE itself if basically an extension of GitHub Atom (which is awesome) and, of course, doesn't come even close to the power of the full Visual Studio. But it is very clean and easy to use. Especially with the new ASP.NET 5 web apps that are very much like Node.js/Angular/etc apps which many people write in simpler editors like Sublime and Atom.

**UPDATE:**

The tooling around it is not as rich (by a lot) as in Visual Studio. Another big caveat is that ASP.NET 5 apps debugging is not supported right now (because they are compiled with Roslyn and not Mono). C# only. Microsoft will add support in the next release though. See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/debugging).

Comment: So could I trust that it would debug with the same quality as visual studio 2015?

Comment: Depends on what are you working on. The tooling around it is not as rich (by a lot) as in Visual Studio. Another big caveat is that ASP.NET 5 apps debugging is not supported right now. C# only. Microsoft will add support in the next release though.

Comment: vscode is Visual Studio online and utilizes Electron to bring it to the desktop.

Comment: @TjGienger I thought that Electron is used to create a cross-platform app using JS and to combine native and JS environments. And Visual Studio Online is a set of project/release management tools that is complement to your IDE, but doesn't allow you to write code. Am I wrong? Can you recommend any futher reading about GitHub Electron and Visual Studio online?